# Creating a dataframe column in python, based on the conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have the following DataFrame (in reality I'm working with around 20 million rows):

```
shop month day sale
1      7     1   10
1      6     1   8
1      5     1   9
2      7     1   10
2      6     1   8
2      5     1   9
```

I want another column: "Prev month sales", where sales are equal to the "Sales of previous month with same day, e.g.

```
   shop month  day  sale prev month sale
    1      7     1   10     8
    1      6     1   8      9
    1      5     1   9      9
    2      7     1   10     8
    2      6     1   8      9
    2      5     1   9      9
```

Comment: It is more complicated as seems. What happen if `30`, `31` days? What February - `28, 29` ?

Comment: Then It will use the same value as the sales column for that row.

Answer (score 2):

One solution using `.concat()`, `set_index()`, and `.loc[]`:

```
# Get index of (shop, previous month, day).
# This will serve as a unique index to look up prev. month sale.
prev = pd.concat((df.shop, df.month - 1, df.day), axis=1)
# Unfortunately need to convert to list of tuples for MultiIndexing
prev = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(prev.values.T)
# old: [tuple(i) for i in prev.values]

# Now call .loc on df to look up each prev. month sale.
sale_prev_month = df.set_index(['shop', 'month', 'day']).loc[prev]

# And finally just concat rather than merge/join operation
#     because we want to ignore index & mimic a left join.
df = pd.concat((df, sale_prev_month.reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1)

   shop  month  day  sale  sale
0     1      7    1    10   8.0
1     1      6    1     8   9.0
2     1      5    1     9   NaN
3     2      7    1    10   8.0
4     2      6    1     8   9.0
5     2      5    1     9   NaN
```

Your new column will be float, not int, [because](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) of the presence of NaNs.

#### Update - an attempt with [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

I don't use dask day to day so this is probably woefully sub-par.  Trying to work around the fact that dask does not implement pandas' MultiIndex.  So, you can concatenate your three existing indices into a string column and lookup on that.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Play around with npartitions or chunksize here!
df2 = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)  

# Get a *single* index of unique (shop, month, day IDs)
# Dask doesn't support MultiIndex
empty = pd.Series(np.empty(len(df), dtype='object'))  # Passed to `meta`
current = df2.loc[:, on].apply(lambda col: '_'.join(col.astype(str)), axis=1,
                               meta=empty)
prev = df2.loc[:, on].assign(month=df2['month'] - 1)\
    .apply(lambda col: '_'.join(col.astype(str)), axis=1, meta=empty)
df2 = df2.set_index(current)

# We know have two dask.Series, `current` and `prev`, in the 
#     concatenated format "shop_month_day".
# We also have a dask.DataFrame, df2, which is indexed by `current`

# I would think we could just call df2.loc[prev].compute(), but
#     that's throwing a KeyError for me, so slightly more expensive:
sale_prev_month = df2.compute().loc[prev.compute()][['sale']]\
    .reset_index(drop=True)

# Now just concat as before
# Could re-break into dask objects here if you really needed to
df = pd.concat((df, sale_prev_month.reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1)
```

Comment: I have a csv file with about 20 million rows and for that the second line of your code takes too much time. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Also, I made a modification to that line of code that was giving you trouble.  Should be at least some speed improvement.